# If-else condition not executing correctly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope the question is not too silly, but I am stuck with it and have tried may things. I have a dropdown in a table row which I am adding dynamically, and I am associating a change event with the dropdown. I have the following code here:

```
$(document).on("change", $('tr').find('select'), function(){

    if ($(this).val() == 0){
        $('#items_selected').text(1);
        alert("2nd time wrong");
    }else{
        alert("2nd time right");
        $('#items_selected').text(parseInt($('#items_selected').text()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
    }
});
```

Now, there is a checkbox, which when checked causes the dropdown (previously disabled) to become enabled.This fires the change event properly, executing the `if` condition in the code above. But when I change the value in the dropdown from the default value of 0 to something else, the event does fire, but again the `if` condition executes, not the else, which should now work. Is there something wrong with my event type (`change`), or are my datatypes (string/number) messed up, or is it something else? I tried `parseInt()` and other things but they didn't work. Can someone help please?

Comment: if you want to find all the gloabal ones then use it : `'tr select'`

Comment: just nitpicking is $(this).val() a string and you are checking it against int?

Comment: What is the result of alerting `$(this).val()` before your if statement?

Comment: I think you should check for selected values text, some thing like$(this).find('option:selected').text();

Comment: post your html dom structure

Comment: @ConnorCMcKee I put this before the if- alert("INIT: " + $(this).val());. Both times it shows INIT: followed by a blank. I thought $(this).val() was the way to get the value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the select text value like `$(this).find("option:selected").val()`

Below code works:

```
$(document).on("change", $('tr').find('select'), function(){    
    if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() == 0){   
        alert($(this).find("option:selected").val());
    }else{
        alert($(this).find("option:selected").val());         
    }
});
```

Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a9x3qpmn/)

Answer (score 0):

In the present code you call `on` on `$(document)`. As a result, in the event handler, `this` will be the `document` (even if you are actually looking at events happening on the dropdown).

You can try something like this:

```js
$("#the-select").on("change", function(){
    // good practice: always use "==="
    if ($(this).val() === "0"){
        $('#items_selected').text(1);
        alert("2nd time wrong");
    }else{
        alert("2nd time right");
        $('#items_selected').text(parseInt($('#items_selected').text()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="the-select">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<div id="items_selected">0</div>
```

If you absolutely want to call `on` on `$(document)` (though I can't see why you would), then keep in mind that `this` won't be your dropdown. Put it in a variable in the upper scope, re-select it in the handler, or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind) your handler to the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but I think the 'on' function must take a selector as an argument, I think, going by the docs, which 'this' would refer to. In a dynamic case at least, a selector inside 'on' is needed. I got it working with ssilas777's solution. But thanks again!

Comment: @user3033194 It does not. The API case your talking about is used if you didn't use a jQuery object, i.e. if you do `$.on(selector, ...)` or if you want to do event delegation. You do not need it in your case`. Loot at their examples: http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Comment: @epascarello That is the point. Why do you want `this` to be `window`?

Comment: @QuentinRoy I agree, but your example uses a static dropdown. My code creates the dropdown dynamically. I tried your snippet in my code, but it wasn't executing for if or else.

Comment: @user3033194 I used another selector because I didn't had your html. But you can use any selector you want. Try replacing `$("#the-select")` with `$(tr select')` as you had in your code. It doesn't matter if it is created dynamically or not.

Comment: You missed the point. the `this` in the OP's code is not a reference to the document... It will be the select that the user changed. That is how event delegation works with `on` in jQuery.

Comment: @epascarello I am sorry. It is possible that we do not understand each other, but with OP's syntax, `this` will be `document` and I believe it is the source of his problem. Try it by yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/810dc2y9/ :-).